# segmentation fault in my code with strcpy

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcpy

I am getting segmentation fault after strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]);
 Not sure what's going wrong here and i would appreciate a hand to understand what's wrong and why i get that segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int value = 5;
    char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8];

    strcpy(buffer_one, "one"); // Put "one" into buffer_one
    strcpy(buffer_two, "two"); // Put "two" into buffer_two
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);

    printf("\n[STRCPY] copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n", strlen(argv[1])); //Copy first argument into buffer_two

    strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]); // <---- here

    printf("[After] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[After] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);     
}
```

Comment: What did you pass as the first argument to the program (i.e. what is `argv[1]`)?

Comment: What does the `strlen(argv[1]))` line print?

Comment: You should check `argc` before assuming something is in `argv[index]`.  It also would not hurt to use `strncpy` to limit the copy to the length of the buffer, since the program has no control over how long `argv[1]` is and could cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: Aside: `buffer_one, buffer_one` ==> `(void*)buffer_one, buffer_one` when supplying `%p` specifier.

Comment: The reason for the failure is largely dependent on how you call this program.  What is the exact command you give to run it?

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible reasons for the seg fault.

1) There is no `argv[1]` , i.e. you try to copy from a NULL pointer (That is... If the program is started with no arguments, `argv[1]` may be accessed but will return a NULL pointer. Consequently, copying from it is illegal and may cause a seg fault). So if you start the program like `./program` the program will crash as `argv[1]` is NULL

2) The length of `argv[1]` exceeds the destination, i.e. 7 chars and a terminating NUL. If so you write out of bounds and may cause a seg fault.

So to get the code correct do:

```
int main(int argv,char * argv[])
{
    char buffer_two[8];
    if ((argc >  1) && (strlen(argv[1]) < 8)) // Make sure arg[1] is there
                                              // Make sure it's not too long
    {
            strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Illegal start of program\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**BTW**

When printing a pointer using `%p` make sure to cast to `void*`

So this

```
printf("[After] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
```

should be

```
printf("[After] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", (void*)buffer_two, buffer_two);
```

Comment: Nice, but `< 8` will do, or `< sizeof buffer_two`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks... Of cause... Maybe I'm too tired and should call it the day. Thanks for correcting me :-)

Comment: Thankful for a closure to this straggling question.

Comment: "make sure to cast to void*" -- whatever for?

Answer (score 2):

There are two primary problems here: you do not check `argc` to see if `argv[1]` exists, and you blindly copy `argv[1]` into the buffer that might not be big enough to fit it.  I've also fixed some of the compiler warnings related to your printf statements.  Here is an example, using your code, of how to handle such things:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if(argc < 2) {
      printf("Please enter an argument when invoking this program\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
    int value = 5;
    char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8];

    strcpy(buffer_one, "one"); // Put "one" into buffer_one
    strcpy(buffer_two, "two"); // Put "two" into buffer_two
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", (void *)buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", (void *)buffer_one, buffer_one);

    printf("\n[STRCPY] copying %zu bytes into buffer_two\n\n", strlen(argv[1])); //Copy first argument into buffer_two

    strncpy(buffer_two, argv[1], 8); // <---- here
    if(buffer_two[7] != '\0'){
       printf("[ERROR] string did not fit into buffer, truncating\n");
       buffer_two[7] = '\0';
    }

    printf("[After] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", (void *)buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[After] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", (void *)buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", (void *)&value, value, value);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check argc value before using argv. Use strcpy only when argc >1 . Make a conditional statement before strcpy()

Eg...

```
int main(int argv,char * argv[])
{
    char buffer[10];
    if (argc >  1 && strlen(argv[1]) < 10)
    {
        strcpy(&buffer[0],argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should run program by

```
./a.out hai
```

hai is the argument passed. Here argc is 2 ,argv[1] = hai